# Is there a text-file, where I can edit the blacklist concerning suspend-to-ram (openSUSE)?

Tags: linux, opensuse, suspend, blacklist

is there (openSUSE 11.2) a text-file, where I can edit the blacklisted programs, which prevent suspending to ram?

Answer (score 0):

[**Seach here**](http://en.opensuse.org/KPowersave) for `blacklist`. But this is only for the KDE part. But I think GNOME has also that possibility.

To find a specific **file**, you could modify the blacklist settings and then search for latest modification inside your home directory (to see which file was changed).

Comment: I can only find PowerDevil (KDE 4.3.1).